# drawing multiple horizontal line in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw multiple horizontal lines that every line starts and ends in specific points, or having a straight line for the mean of two section of the plot. For example, I want to have these two red straight lines in my plot shown in the picture. How can I do that in R? 
[image]

---

For two break points how can I fix the equation below?:

```
BREAK1 = 1962
BREAK2 = 1985
df$grp = ifelse(df$year > BREAK2,"C",if(df$year < BREAK1){"A"}else if (df$year > BREAK1 & df$year < BREAK2){"B"})
```

Comment: have a look at `?ggplot2::geom_segment`. Generally, please provide reproducible examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a quick way to do it. A quick background, if you fit a intercept only linear model, lm(y ~ 1) , the intercept will be the mean. So what you need is to define your segments and use geom_smooth with this formula, you will get the mean line:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
BREAK = 1985
df = data.frame(year=1960:2020,value=runif(61))
df$grp = ifelse(df$year > BREAK,"B","A")

ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=value)) + 
geom_line() + geom_point() + 
geom_vline(xintercept=BREAK,linetype="dashed")+
geom_smooth(aes(group=grp),formula=y~1,method="lm",col="red",se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was a great help. @StupidWolf

Comment: Do you know how I can add a legend for lines? In your example, for different lines exist and I want to add a nice legend for them in the plot.@StupidWolf

Comment: you put the col inside the aes, e.g aes(group=grp,col=grp)

Comment: I have a plot which has three horizontal lines for means. How can I change the formula for df$grp to draw those three lines? thank you so much in advance @ StupidWolf

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question. can you be more specific about where you are facing a problem

Comment: In your example, imagine we have two break points instead of one. So, then we should have three straight lines for three sections, which represent the mean of each section between BREAK points.  I face the same problem but this time I have two break points.@ StupidWolf

Comment: you use ifelse(df$year,BREAKS,labels=..), please take a look at the function cut

Comment: Please look at the equation that I just added to my question, below the picture of the question. how can I fix the equation? it does not work now@ StupidWolf

Comment: df$grp = cut(df$year,breaks=c(-Inf,1962,1985,+Inf),labels=c("A","B","C")). Again please look at the function cut

Comment: You are really great. Thank you a world @ StupidWolf